# Unable to process multipart/form-data from ajax in JAX-RS jersey web service

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I am sending a form data request from the following Javascript:

```
xmlHttpReq.open("POST", "https://server.com/resource", true);
formData = new FormData(form);
xmlHttpReq.send(formData);
```

The server code running in a tomcat container is as following:

```
@POST
@Path("{computation}")
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded,multipart/form-data"})
String doPost(MultivaluedMap <String, String> formParams) {
    ....
    return strVar;
}
```

The server receives the content type

```
content-type="multipart/form-data; 
boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryM1A3izVTDMdn1xsJ"
```

and throws the following exception:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, 
and Java type javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, 
and MIME media type multipart/form-data; 
boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryM1A3izVTDMdn1xsJ was not found.
```

How can I get the server to accept the `multipart/form-data` request? It works fine for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your @Consumes should be formatted like this:

```
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded","multipart/form-data")
```